# Ajax url's dynamic IP address replacement

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to web development. When using Ajax, the url's IP address is specified manually. Consider there are dozens of functions using the IP address, replacing IP address is not trivial. One scenario is dev and deployment using different machines with different IP addresses. Is there a way to do it elegantly?

e.g.,

```
function login(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://192.168.1.110/login",  // could be other IP address
        data: {..},
        success: function (response) {
          
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
}

function register(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://192.168.1.110/register",  // same IP address as login
        data: {..},
        success: function (response) {
          
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Store it in a variable and replace the hard coded values with that variable. Then you only need to change it in one place

Answer (score 0):

```
window.serverIp = "http://192.168.1.110";
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serverIp+"/register",  // same IP address as login
        data: {..},
        success: function (response) {
          
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
```

you can set global variable for your server ip by simply adding serverIp variable with window.serverIp = "your ip";